# IntelliJ IDEA keymap on OS X

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, keymapping

Is there a keymap for IntelliJ on Mac which does not override or is not overridden by system shortcuts ? This <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> for autocompletion really pisses me off. I think it's disrespect to os x environment.

Answer (score 2):

You can read this manual [IntelliJ IDEA Mac OS X Keymap](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_Mac.pdf). Here is a screen capture. 
[image]

Comment: This interferes with Spotlight shortcut

Comment: @DenisMikhaylov:  You could remap the Spotlight shortcut, or this shortcut, at will.